# Memory Usage python matplotlib.mlab.griddata

Tags: python, memory, matplotlib, matplotlib.mlab

Using the `griddata`-function of `matplotlib.mlab` I'm facing some problems with memory usage. The function is called several times by the `scipy.integrate.quad`-function. The task manager tells me that python allocates up to ~1,8 GB memory before it crashes without an error message. I don't get why the function allocates more and more memory with every call and I guess that's the key point to the crash. Can anyone explain me why this is happening? I'm using python 2.7.9 on Windows.

Comment: Do you run a 32bit or 64bit Windows and Python installation? 2GB seems to be the memory limit for a single process in 32bit systems, that could be the reason your code causes a crash. On [this Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/Dn613959(v=vs.85).aspx) you can read more.

Comment: The machine is running 64bit Windows, but the Python installation is indeed 32bit. Thanks for this hint. Neverthelss I do not understand why the script is allocating so much memory. I could trace the problem to the griddata function, but I have no clue why it is allocating so much memory.